# Question and Answer Both Getting Deleted

Tags: support

The following question: [Does contemplation activity, before hand, give rise to the mental image?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/18045) and the answer has been ddelted. Like to know the reasoning behind this? I believe the answer was an accepted answer too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post page says: *Deleted by Community 12 hours ago*.

[Community](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=profile) is not a real person. Its a background process designed to keep the site clean.

It does things like:

- [Remove abandoned questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006)

An abandoned question risks deletion by Community if:

"If the question is more than **30 days old**, and ..."

• **has −1 or lower score**

• has no answers

• is not locked

---

**Answer updated.**

I think I found the reason. Digging a little deeper I found another post; [How does deleting work and how can a post be deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that).

A post can be deleted by the System if:

"... By the system:

6.The system will automatically delete any post flagged six times as offensive or spam.

7.The system will automatically delete closed (not as a duplicate), unlocked questions with zero or negative score having no positively scored or accepted answers or pending reopen votes, that were closed 9 or more days ago and haven't been edited in the past 9 days.

8.The system will automatically delete unlocked, unanswered questions that have negative score after 30 days.

9.The system will automatically delete unlocked, unanswered questions with score of zero (or one if the owner is deleted), fewer than 1.5 views per day on average, and fewer than two comments after 365 days.

**10.The system will automatically delete any question (and its answers) or answer with a negative score when its owner’s account is deleted.**

11.The system will automatically delete questions migrated to other sites after 30 days. Note that this applies only for the original question created on the original site (the “migration stub”), not the question newly created on the other site as a result of the migration. Questions autodeleted under this criterion still have their revision histories visible to everyone, and links to them redirect to the new question instead of showing an error page.

12.Answers with zero or negative score that receive six recommend deletion reviews in the low-quality-posts review queue are automatically deleted “in review”. Answers can be kicked into this queue either automatically or with very low quality and not an answer flags, and can be removed from the queue if enough looks OK reviews are cast against them.

See: The Community user deleted my question! What gives? at Help Center... "

Comment: Well it had an answer and was a accepted answer. Above says `has no answers`. The answer also got deleted with the question. Use of `and` imply all 3 conditions have to be met if older than 30 day.

Comment: Good point. Answer updated.

Comment: OK. I am voting to undelete the question and answer through the question was a bit on the short side the answer I provided would have had value to a would be reader.

Comment: Well, I too think that your answer contains some gems. The question though, seems a bit confused but behind the lines I understand what OP asks. I will reopen the question if you can edit the question a bit to better reflect what is being asked. The reason I want you to edit it is because of your answer. It shows you have understood the question well.

Comment: OK Sure will do that.

Comment: @SumindaSirinathS.Dharmasena Yes I guess that the user asked to be deleted (i.e. that they asked StackExchange, didn't ask the moderators), and that their negatively-voted question was automatically deleted when their account was deleted.

Comment: OK. I have edited the question.